# IF - ELSE Condition in Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I want to use If Else Condition inside a For loop. If that condition satisfies then perform the function name "Success1". That Success1 is returning some output. I have maintained that Sucess1 keyword under the Keyword section of the test suite.

```
'''code'''
***TestCase***
${Total}  set variable  0
:FOR   ${i}   IN RANGE   1  ${RCount}
    \     log to console  ${Total}
    \     ${CountryName} =  get text   //table[@id='resultTable']/tbody/tr[${i}]/td[4]
    \     log to console   Captured country name ${CountryName}
    \     run keyword if   '${CountryName}' == 'United States'  ${TempValue} =  Success1  ${i}  ${Total}
    \     ${Total} =  set variable  ${TempValue}
          sleep  ${timeout}
*** Keywords ***
Success1
    [Arguments]   ${i}  ${Total}
          ${Emp} =  get text  //table[@id='resultTable']/tbody/tr[${i}]/td[6]
          ${Emp} =  convert to integer  ${Emp}
          log to console  Captured No. of Employees ${Emp}
          ${Total} =  Evaluate  ${Emp}+${Total}
          log to console  ${Total}- Final Value
```

Note:

This for loop is under one test case. Sucess1 is the keyword that I have created to perform actions. The output of the function will be saved to "TempValue"  Variable.

On Executing this code I am receiving "No keyword with the name ' =' found." Error.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this line:

```
run keyword if   '${CountryName}' == 'United States'  ${TempValue} =  Success1  ${i}  ${Total}
```

The way robot is parsing this is that if the condition is true, it will run the keyword named `${TempValue} =` If `${TempValue}` is an empty string, that means it will try to run the keyword `=`. Since there is no keyword by that name, robot gives the error "No keyword with the name ' ='.

In other words, you can't assign variables inside of `run keyword if`. The very next cell after the condition must be a keyword name.

Comment: Thanks, Bryan...  Is there any workaround available to resolve this. That Success1 function will return "Total" which I will be using it in the main function inside TestCase for further iterations?

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
${TempValue} =    Run Keyword If    '${CountryName}'=='United States'  Success1    ${i}    ${Total}
```